# FBSDKLog: Unable to obtain a key window

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, fbsdk

When I start my application I get the following log:

```
FBSDKLog: Unable to obtain a key window, marking <UIWindow: 0x100e7b260; 
frame = (0 0; 375 667);
hidden = YES; 
gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2832a3900>; 
layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x283ca01a0>> as keyWindow
```

Do I have something misconfigured or can I safely ignore this error? The logging of events seems to work.

Using FBSDKCoreKit 5.8.0

Comment: I also started getting this message recently and haven't touched the FBSDK configuration in my app for months. I haven't updated since 5.2.3

Comment: FBSDKCoreKit 5.14.0 still presents the same issue

Comment: Any solutions yet, I am also facing same issue.